# How can I generate a random color palette within certain parameters?

Tags: color-theory, resource-recommendations

Is there a good configurable applications to generate random palettes? Found a [color scheme](http://www.colormixture.com/mix) generator that can generate random palettes, but its random part isn't configurable. I need to set minimum and maximum saturation of colors, brightness, to fix a pair of colors etc, is there any good tools for that?

Comment: "But its random part isn't configurable." - isn't that the point of *random*? What *exactly* are you looking for? Have you considered writing your own? This type of thing is pretty simple if you know what you actually want

Comment: You mean like [Adobe Color](https://color.adobe.com/)?